# Haskell display tree function

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm trying to write a function, which displays a tree, substituting tree blocks with / or \ (left or right child) plus Int value under them.
Tree is defined as follows:

```
    data Tree x 
      = Null
      | Leaf x
      | Node (Tree x) x (Tree x)
      deriving Show
```

and it can contain only five one digit values, so for example following tree:

```
    Node(Node(Leaf 1)(2)(Leaf 3))(3)(Node(Null)(4)(Leaf 5))
```

would be displayed this way:

```
             3
           /   \
          2     4
         / \     \
        1   3     5
```

I suppose that with more nodes and higher trees there would be some overlapping of nodes due to limited space, but it should be fine in this case, cause the function is to deal with binary search trees alone.

I have a function at my disposal, which takes [[bool]] and prints lines, substituting booleans with characters, but... I have no idea how it could be used in this particular case... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the example you give, does the 5 have to be the right child? I guess that to whoever can help you (I am just starting to learn Haskell so it won't be me) it might make a difference.

Comment: yes, it has to be right child, Node(Null)(5)(Leaf 5) states it explicitly. I'm a beginner, too. Just started to discover magic of haskell few weeks ago :)

Comment: Have a look at how the tree drawing function is implemented in the standard library, it should help you with your exercise: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.1/doc/html/src/Data-Tree.html#drawTree

Comment: I meant Node(Null)(4)(Leaf 5)

Comment: Yeah... Thanks Grzegorz, it looks amazing. I imported Data.Tree into my module, but now ghci doesn't like my definition of a tree as well as a function returning a list of all possible binary search trees, which takes a list of integers as an input.

Comment: @user1166935: Do you get a name clash? If that's the case you can either rename your types and functions so they don't conflict with Data.Tree, or you can `import qualified Data.Tree as T` and then access functions from the Data.Tree module with the `T.` prefix, for example: `T.drawTree`. But of course this function will not work on the type you defined, but only on the tree type from the Data.Tree module.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, I'm an absolute beginner